# "Modernized" Google OAUTH - How to perform it in the browser (Chrome for Android) without adding the account to the device?

Tags: google-oauth

This is in reference to:

https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

which asks to post questions on stack overflow under #google-oauth.

I've been playing with the new Chrome Tabs based approach, and the user experience is really bad for @gmail accounts not already present in system settings.

I've got an email app, some users want to be able to use their (secondary, auxiliary) @gmail accounts in my app, without having to add them into system settings.

This is the main reason really to use web based OAUTH at all in a native mobile app (from my perspective), since for accounts present in system settings, I just use Google Play Services, it's really simple for the user, it works, fine.

OK, on to the issues. And please consider this an "issue report".

( note to SO moderators -- I'll reiterate, Google people asked to post feedback here on SO, there does not appear to be any other feedback channel )

1 - User wants to add a new @gmail account (not present in system settings), I launch the approval URL in a Chrome Tab.

[image]

Chrome shows the main @gmail account from system settings (to be expected I guess).

Bad: To switch to another account -- which was the point of coming to this screen in the first place -- the user has to tap the account name, top right, then tap "Manage Accounts", then "Go incognito" (as "Manage accounts" will take the user to a screen for adding another @gmail account into Android, not what he/she wanted).

Result: the user just won't know this, it's complicated, non-intuitive. And I reiterate, the only reason for "coming to" this screen was to authorize an account not present in system settings.

Possible solution: an easier way to log in as "other gmail account" without having to know about "go incognito".

2 - User needs to re-authorize a @gmail account that's 1) not present in system settings and 2) already present in the app.

Perhaps he/she accidentally took the permission away, maybe something else, OK, the app brings up the approval screen, setting `login_hint` to the already known email.

This is in WebView:

[image]

Very easy to understand. The account (email) is pre-filled from `login_hint`, the user taps Next, enters the password, grants the permission, done!

And this is what it looks like in a Chrome Tab:

[image]

What in the world is this?

I guess Chrome realized that the account passed as `login_hint` is not present in the phone's Settings.

Right, it's not. That was the point of opening this screen (and not just using Google Play Services OAUTH utils).

I can't even figure out, from the user's perspective, on this screen, how to switch to my specific account which is not in the phone's system settings.

Now you may ask -- why let the user work with a @gmail account that's not there in the phone's system settings?

That's what users want, that's why.

Not everyone likes the Gmail app (OK?)

And not everyone wants to have a list of dozens and dozens of things that Android will try to sync under each @gmail account (magazines? fitness? games? TV?... battery optimizations, right?)

So they turn to my app which lets them add @gmail accounts with (for their main account, I guess) and without (for others) having to add them into system settings.

Now questions:

1 - The new UI flow for non-system accounts is broken, hello Google'rs, do you confirm?

2 - Hello Google'rs do you agree that non-system accounts would be the primary reason to go to "web-like" OAUTH, since system accounts are handled by GoogleOauthUtil.getToken anyway?

3 - Do you agree that the flow is simply broken right now?

4 - Do you have a plan, can you come up with a plan to fix this?

Comment: Regardless of what Google might say on their blog, these questions are unfortunately off-topic on Stack Overflow. While your post is detailed and well-developed, Stack Overflow is not a feedback board nor an issue tracker. Please leave a comment on their blog instead.

Comment: @HolgerJust Perhaps you can ask Google to stop "pointing to" SO as their feedback venue?

Comment: Unfortunately some Googlers tend to still send people over to Stack Overflow indiscriminately. This issue was discussed before on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3966/217589) as well as in an [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/421705). Unfortunately, this is painful for users like you who invest time here. Without these rules however, Stack Overflow would quickly become a swampy mess instead of the (mostly) high-quality resource it is today.

Comment: Sorry that you feel this way @HolgerJust. We have a tag dedicated to `google-oauth` which we monitor, and I hoped that questions related to migrating an OAuth flow from web-view to browser-based would be relevant and useful (and in many cases relevant for other OAuth providers too, though not in this case). The intent wasn't to be indiscriminate or encourage off-topic posts such as feedback. Perhaps this question can be rephrased to "How to perform OAuth in the browser to Google without adding an account to the device?", which might be a more relevant question under the `google-oauth` tag?

Comment: @KostyaVasilyev can I suggest rephrasing this so it's more a question? I don't have a good answer for you right now, but I think the topic of how to do a browser-based OAuth flow on Android to Google without the account being added is a valid question, and I want to investigate what possible solutions there might be.

Comment: @WilliamDenniss Well, it's not really a question, but I can _technically_ rephrase.

In terms of user experience, working with non-system accounts, right now, in WebView, is very simple and easy to understand.

With the new approach, it's really bad and possibly broken completely.

Now the questions as promised:

- Is there a good way to do OAUTH for non-system accounts with the new approach (I know the answer to this one, "no")?

- Why is it so bad?

- What steps will be taken to fix it?

- When?

Comment: And I'll reiterate: if the device has Google Play Services (most do) and if it's a system account, then using GMS is (most of the time) all I need.

I guess for many apps, who use Google OAUTH as a way to log into their app, the (one, mostly) system account is fine.

For me, people want to access email in accounts not present in system settings. This needs web based OAUTH, and this case specifically is broken.

Feel free to contact me at kmansoft / gmail. I've also got a Google Play Services OAUTH issue to report, not sure where I can do that (if you have a pointer, it would be great).

Comment: @WilliamDenniss Has your investigation turned up anything?

Comment: If you sign out of chrome, it will get you to the password page instead of Android add account. However, I'm still looking for a way to do this without logging out.